# transform this function using normal programming code and without using R functions

Tags: r

I have this function in R from a previous question here

```
shift <- function(d, k) rbind( tail(d,k), head(d,-k), deparse.level = 0 )
```

this function will rotate the data frame d by K, that's mean it will take K rows from the end of the data frame and place them on the top.

I want to create the same function(in the same language) but without using R pre-made functions(head, tail,...), but only using basics of programming.(for , ...)

How this can be done?

Comment: Out of curiosity...why ? for loops are usually much slower in R...

Comment: @digEmAll :  i want to do it in multiple ways, that why

Comment: @digEmAll - you couldn't be more wrong with that generic statement on the speed of loops in R. They are not as inefficient as your comment suggests if you create the required storage before the loop begins. I agree with you if you meant as a replacement for vectorised operations in R.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Sorry, but no; loop will be always slower than index or vectorised operation because the cost of executing R code is significant in comparison to native code (at least till there will be a JIT in R engine [-: ). Allocation is a problem here too, but not the only one.

Comment: @mbq - didn't I say that? See last line of my comment. I may have misread the intent of @digEmAll's comment. I guess it depends what they mean by "much slower"? Than what? Loops aren't slow in R - that was a problem in S-PLUS. Of course, using them in place of vectorised operations will be far slower.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: you're right my comment was too much inaccurate. I apologize for that. Vectorized operations are usually faster, but that doesn't mean that for-loops are **always** slower in R.

Comment: (downvoted because the question is ambiguous, and apparently not even what the questioner wants.)

Comment: @Richie Cotton : sorry , i made a new question , and your right sacha's code works perfectly , but i need it in another language  now :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I don't know what you mean with `without using R functions` since pretty much everything is an R function, but here is a solution using only the very generic `nrow()` (Number of rows of a matrix), `%%` (modulus) and `seq_len` (equivalent to `1:length(x)` except that it works better):

```
m <- matrix(1:40,,2,byrow=TRUE)

shift2 <- function(d, k) d[(seq_len(nrow(d))-k-1)%%(nrow(d))+1,]

shift2(m,5)


      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   31   32
 [2,]   33   34
 [3,]   35   36
 [4,]   37   38
 [5,]   39   40
 [6,]    1    2
 [7,]    3    4
 [8,]    5    6
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    9   10
[11,]   11   12
[12,]   13   14
[13,]   15   16
[14,]   17   18
[15,]   19   20
[16,]   21   22
[17,]   23   24
[18,]   25   26
[19,]   27   28
[20,]   29   30
```

If you mean with "normal programming code" that it shouldn't be vectorized then, well, you are learning either the wrong language in the right way or the right language in the wrong way. Everytime you come up with a vectorized solution instead of `for` loops you are happy in R.

But if you really really want to do this with loops here is exactly the same function unvectorized:

```
shift3 <- function(d, k) 
{
  out <- matrix(,nrow(d),ncol(d))
  sorts <- (seq_len(nrow(d))-k-1)%%(nrow(d))+1
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(d))) out[i,] <- d[sorts[i],]
  return(out)
}
```

Proof they are all equal:

```
all(shift(m,5) == shift2(m,5) & shift2(m,5) == shift3(m,5))
[1] TRUE
```

## EDIT:

Actually `shift3()` there STILL contained a lot of vectorizations, showing just how native that is in R. Here is a fully unvectorized version:

```
shift3 <- function(d, k) 
{
  out <- matrix(,nrow(d),ncol(d))
  sor <- numeric(1)
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(d))) 
  {
    if (i-k < 1) sor <- nrow(d)-k+i else sor <- i-k
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(d))) out[i,j] <- d[sor,j]
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: thanks , i did not understand the code to be honest, how can i do it in java or C# for example ?? on a text file

Comment: @smack: Sacha has given you what you asked for.  If you want a translation into Java or C#, then ask for this in a new question.